# QML: QT Project does not run after modifying the code

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm learning the QT basic, starting the new project `QT Quick APP Empty`. Running for first time, the app run. Modifying the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.4

Window { x: 100; y: 100; width: 100; height: 100; visible: true }
```

Output response:

```
17:34:02: Starting /home/PC/Documents/Projects/QT_APP/build-FirstAPP-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Release/FirstAPP ...
```

Nothing besides that happens. Am I forgetting anything?

### Updating

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have added "visible: true" because it is the cause of the trivial error that other users pointed out, but according to what you indicated in the comments even correcting that error it continues to fail. My issue is to eliminate that error and redirect the community to look for the other possible causes of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, I will

Answer (score -2):

Worked, after I Clean and build project again!